# How to set a startup page in Expression Blend for an MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, expression-blend

We are hosting a Silverlight application inside an ASP.NET MVC view. There isn't an aspx or an html page that we can choose as the startup - we need to launch the application using a URL.

It seems that Expression Blend doesn't allow this startup configuration - you must choose a specific page. As a result you can't start/debug the application from Expression Blend - it complains about startup page not being set.

Is there a solution/workaround that would allow us to start an ASP.NET MVC-hosted Silverlight application from Blend?

Comment: How about a temp ASP.Net startup page that just redirects to the URL you require for it to work? Then Blend should be satisfied it has a startup page and your app does not care who calls it.

Answer (score 0):

What I have been doing, is to create a URL route (in your ASP MVC Global.asax.cs) that catches whatever page your Silverlight application is trying to hit. Instead of returning that .aspx page or a 404, it should hit the controller and return your view that displays the silverlight app (assuming the route is set up correctly).

For example,

```
// route to catch Silverlight test page
routes.MapRoute(
      "SilverlightTestUrl",
      "Project.SilverlightTestPage.aspx", // whatever page it's trying to start
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Silverlight" }
);

// make sure the silverlight route is before the default 'catch all' route
routes.MapRoute(
      "Default", // Route name
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Silverlight", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

EDIT: although sorry, I guess this doesn't help the issue of being able to run the project from Expression Blend. I'm not a big fan of blend, I don't know why they didn't jsut incorporate some of the features from Blend into Visual Studio.  Visual Studio's XAML editor is much better than blend.